# Reading Genetic Algorithm Code in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I am working the text, "Genetic Algorithms with Python"by Clinton Sheppard and struggling to learn Python 3 at the same time.

I'm hoping someone out there can help me interpret some Python 3 code correctly.  By that I mean, the code works - it does what it is supposed to do - but I need help understanding why.  Here's the first block of code:

import random

```
geneSet = " abcdef....zA...Z!."
target = "Hello World!"
def generate_parent(length):
    genes = []
    while len(genes) < length:  # limited to length number of iterations
    sampleSize = min(length - len(genes), len(geneSet))
    print("Current sample size: {}".format(sampleSize))
    print(genes.extend(random.sample(geneSet, sampleSize)))

return ''.join(genes)
```

Basically, this method here is used to generate  a random string from the gene set.  I see that it takes as input parameter length.  I'll assume length = 12.  First, an empty list genes is created.  Then the while loop ( which is limited to length iterations ) obtains a sampleSize by taking the minimum of (length - len(genes) and len(geneSet).  Using 12 as length this works out to min(12 - 0, 54) the result being 12.  A random sample of sampleSize (12) is sampled from the geneSet and the genes list is extended by such.

I'm having difficulty seeing the need for the final line of code "return ''.join(genes)".  Or how it is this while loop ever goes through more than a single iteration since in the second to last line of code the genes list is extended from the geneSet by sampleSize.

.... and this is just hello world :) I think, as is usually the case, I'm overlooking the flat out obvious but if someone could take a few moments to explain this code in their own words I'd appreciate the different perspective.

Thanks!

Comment: `random.sample()` cannot pick more elements than there are in the set being sampled.  The `while` loop is therefore necessary to handle the case of `length` being greater than `len(geneSet)`.  As for the `return`, it turns this generated list of characters into a string, which is presumably a more convenient form elsewhere in the program.

Comment: I see, author is programming defensively for that case, in which None is returned unless and until the current sampleSize drops into the proper range. i.e.  Thank yuo

Answer (score 0):

`"".join(genes)` ist used to combine all the single entries of the genes list into one single string. `str.join(sequence)` takes takes all entries of sequence and seperates them be `str`. As the author needs one string only consisting of genes, `""` is used as `str` so the single characters in the string are seperated by nothing.

The while loop is used (as jasonharper already mentioned) is used to create a string whose length is larger than the gene_set, as `random.sample()` can only pick as much samples as there are elements to be sampled from.

I am currently working on the same book, maybe we can help each other out.